# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when a header is present on the requested source

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

Sorry for asking this question when it's a lot of answers to these questions out there already, but I have tried almost everything and it's still not working. I'm making an API call to an API hosted on replit. This has worked fine until yesterday, I don't know what I did yesterday that f*cked up my code. When making the API call, I get the CORS error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, but I have a header with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in my response.

Really appreciate all your help!

API code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(cors())

app.post('/invoicing', cors(), async (req, res) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('crossorigin', 'true')
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); 
    try {
        const product = await stripe.products.create({
            name: 'Test'
        })

        const price = await stripe.prices.create({
            product: product.id,
            unit_amount: 10000,
            currency: 'nok',
        })

    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            name: 'Daniel Olsen',
            email: 'olsen.daniel04@gmail.com',
            description: 'Customer',
        })

        const invoiceItem = await stripe.invoiceItems.create({
            customer: customer.id,
            price: price.id,
        })

        const invoice = await stripe.invoices.create({
            customer: customer.id,
            auto_advance: true,
        })

        const invoiceFinalize = await stripe.invoices.finalizeInvoice(invoice.id)

        console.log(invoiceFinalize)
        console.log(customer)
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Yeeet'
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.json({
            message: "Payment failed",
            success: false
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: "I have a header with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" -- I'm shooting in the dark a bit, but maybe the [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) of your requests has changed since yesterday, or the server's allowed-origin value has changed? (You can try setting "`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`" temporarily while you troubleshoot.)  . . . . . . . If necessary, you have an older git commit you can fall back to ...right? -- If not, this may be a relatively painless opportunity to learn that lesson (#GIT:_Because_sometimes_you_fvck_up #RealisticSoftwareSlogans)

Comment: I've tried to restore my version from yesterday, but still nothing. The only thing I ask, and find really weird, is that I have a header with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on my response, but that header is not registered when the POST method is called. My question is why this happens? I'm relatively new when it comes to express, but almost every post on the whole internet says that the solution I've tried is what should be done, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I fixed it somehow. I just rewrote the whole API and removed the res.header()'s and replaced it with only cors(). It worked